# How can I write a Perl script that reads from another file?

Tags: perl, statistics

I want to write a Perl Script that reads a file.txt with columns of numbers,

```
20  30  12
31  20  54
63  30  21
11  12  10
```

and do some calculations, for example the mean. I don't know how to declare and initialize it.
I've got this example, in which is looking for the median, and it has the data declared, in my case, the data is in a file, not in the script and want to calculate the median.
there is it..
    #!/usr/bin/perl

```
#data points 
@vals = ( 33, 23, 55, 39, 41, 46, 38, 52, 34, 29, 27, 51, 33, 28 ); 
print "UNSORTED: @vals\n"; 

#sort data points 
@vals = sort(@vals); 
print "SORTED: @vals\n"; #test to see if there are an even number of data points 
if( @vals % 2 == 0) { 

#if even then: 
$sum = $vals[(@vals/2)-1] + $vals[(@vals/2)]; 
$med = $sum/2; 
print "The median value is $med\n";
}
else{ 
#if odd then: 
print "The median value is $vals[@vals/2]\n";
} 
exit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shell one-liner multiply first col with second one :

```
perl -lane 'print $F[0] * $F[1]' <FILE>
```

**EDIT:** And the perl script version with your new requirements and the file with 3 cols :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my (@vals, $sum, $med);

while (<>) {
    @vals = split;

    print "UNSORTED: @vals\n"; 

    #sort data points 
    @vals = sort(@vals); 
    print "SORTED: @vals\n"; #test to see if there are an even number of data points 

    if(@vals % 2 == 0) { 
        #if even then: 
        $sum = $vals[(@vals/2)-1] + $vals[(@vals/2)]; 
        $med = $sum/2; 
        print "The median value is $med\n";
    }
    else{ 
        #if odd then: 
        print "The median value is $vals[@vals/2]\n";
    } 

    print "\n";
}
```

You may understand what's going on instead of just cut & paste ;)

To run the script :

```
./script.pl file_with_cols.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to do some calculations .e.g:

Comment: To initialize, just add "my" to your array : my @vals = ....
You should use : "use strict; use warnings;" too and indent your code !

Comment: Thanks! this works very well. you're a great man. (only one small problem, with script, it gives the median for rows, not columns), but it's fine I will try to fix it somehow. Thanks again.

Comment: If you feel that the respond is useful, you can "upvote" it. If it fits your needs, you should "accept" the reply, that's how stackoverflow works, thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) command.  Plenty of good examples on that page.

Answer (score 1):

Here are suggested functions to use (see the [function reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/index-functions.html)):

1. Open your file for reading: use the `open` function
2. Loop through each line: `while (my $line = <$filehandle>)`
3. Remove the trailing newline: use `chomp`
4. Extract the values from each line: use the `split` function
5. Store the values in an array: use `push`

To verify that your array has what you want at the end:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@vals;
```

### UPDATE

Without giving you the entire answer (since this is homework) have a look at the sample code in each entry of the function reference.

Here's something to get you started:

```
open my $filehandle, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't open $filename";
while (my $line = <$filehandle>) {
    # do stuff with $line
}
close $filehandle;
```

Comment: this sounds interesting, could you revise my script and put some of that functions on it. Thanks.