# How can I write a Perl Script that reads from a file?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I write a Perl script that reads from another file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237130/how-can-i-write-a-perl-script-that-reads-from-another-file)

I want to write a Perl Script that reads a file.txt with columns of numbers,

```
20  30  12
31  20  54
63  30  21
11  12  10
```

and do some calculations, for example the mean, median, etc. I don't know how to declare and initialize it.

I've got this example, which is looking for the median.   It has the data declared in a file, not in the script, and I want to calculate the median.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

#data points 
@vals = ( 33, 23, 55, 39, 41, 46, 38, 52, 34, 29, 27, 51, 33, 28 ); 
print "UNSORTED: @vals\n"; 

#sort data points 
@vals = sort(@vals); 
print "SORTED: @vals\n"; #test to see if there are an even number of data points 
if( @vals % 2 == 0) { 

    #if even then: 
    $sum = $vals[(@vals/2)-1] + $vals[(@vals/2)]; 
    $med = $sum/2; 
    print "The median value is $med\n";
}
else{ 
    #if odd then: 
    print "The median value is $vals[@vals/2]\n";
} 
exit;
```

Thanks for any suggestion. ;)